# MVC 5 ASP.NET Street Address Validation

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have the following Profile class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MyValidation.Models
{
    public class Profile : ValidationAttribute
    {

        [Required]
        public string Name
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        [Required]
        [Range(5, 99)]
        public int Age
        {
            get;
            set;
        }


        public string Street
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public string City
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public string Zip
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public string State
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
}
```

And View:

```
@model MyValidation.Models.Profile

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div> 
        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            @Html.ValidationSummary()
            <p>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Name)</p>
            <p>Your Full Name: @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name)</p>
            <p>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Age)</p>
            <p>Your current age: @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Age)</p>
            <p>Your full address: 
            <br />@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Street)</p>
            @:City: @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.City)
            @:State: @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.State)
            @:Zip Code: @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Zip)
            <input type="submit" value="Submit Form" />
        }
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

How would I make it so that the validation for the the Street Address depends on other values/attributes in profile?

If the user does not enter a Street, City, State, or ZIP, it should allow the user to submit the form. But if the User enters just a state but neither of the other 3, it should not allow it.

It's either, they are all filled out, or none at all.

How would I do this?

After googling a bit, I tried [Compare()] but that did not work

**EDIT**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Home
        public ActionResult Index(Profile profile)
        {
            Profile _profile = profile ?? new Profile();

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_profile.Street) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(_profile.State))
                ModelState.AddModelError("Address", "All Address fields have to be empty, OR full");

            return View(_profile);
        }


    }
```

I think I figured it out, but I am not sure if this is the "right" way to do it?

Comment: Remove the `: ValidationAttribute` as your model class is not an attribute.

Comment: Thank you , what is the point of Validation Attribute then? If you're making a custom validation?

Answer (score 0):

That way is not the right way because || will return false even if all of the conditions are false and will return true if one of the conditions is true.
Here's how I know that will work

```
if((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_profile.Street) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(_profile.State) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(_profile.City) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(_profile.Zip)) && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_profile.Street) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(_profile.State) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(_profile.City) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(_profile.Zip)))
{
ModelState.AddModelError("Address", "All Address fields have to be empty, OR full");
}
```